# Fragments vs shared preferences

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

Can any one differentiate Fragments and shared preferences on android.

Because,

Right now i have a screen which contains an edittext box and button,if i click that button after giving proper input it should return some data according to user's input on the textbox which is on the same screen, the resultant value is from the webservice by consuming it(SOAP method)...

Here my problem is, i want to show that answer on the tabhost's tab which is on the next screen...Have i to use fragment concept or shared preference concept?
Can any one help me?

Thanks for your precious time......

Comment: @blackbelt  when i am trying to show that answer on any tab of a tabhost which is on the next screen,its not working.It just showing the answer on the separate screen,but the screen i mentioned to show the result is one of the tab of the tabhost.How to overcome this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those concepts are not related.

SharedPreferences is used to save data in a persistent way.

Fragments are re-usable UI components.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: when i am trying to show that answer on any tab of a tabhost which is on the next screen,its not working.It just showing the answer on the separate screen,but the screen i mentioned to show the result is one of the tab of the tabhost.How to overcome this

Answer (score 1):

> Shared Preference and Fragment are not related with each other , both
>   are totally different . One is used for Ui Design and another is used
>   for Save Data.
>
> **A Fragment** is, generally, a chunk of user interface with its own life
>   cycle. If that sounds a lot like an Activity, that’s because it is a
>   lot like an Activity. However, a Fragment is different from an
>   Activity, in that a Fragment must exist within an Activity. A Fragment
>   doesn’t have to be paired with the same Activity each time it’s
>   instantiated, which gives it some flexibility. Also like an Activity,
>   a Fragment need not contain any user interface.
>
> The **SharedPreferences** class provides a general framework that allows
>   you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data
>   types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data:
>   booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist
>   across user sessions (even if your application is killed).
>
> You can use shared preference to save data and access that on next
>   screen activity or you can pass that resultant string to intent using
>   .putExtra() .

Comment: One doubt!...when i am trying to show that answer on any tab of a tabhost which is on the next screen,its not working.It just showing the answer on the separate screen,but the screen i mentioned to show the result is one of the tab of the tabhost.How to overcome this